# Network unreachable: robots.txt unreachable

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I'm getting error "**Network unreachable: robots.txt unreachable**" when trying to add my website on Google `Webmaster tools ->` http://www.hyponomist.com/

You can check my [robots.txt at here](http://www.hyponomist.com/robots.txt) and [sitemap.xml at here](http://www.hyponomist.com/sitemap.xml)

I have reading other posts here and there, but could not solve/understand. what is causing this issue. Also, I tried downloading a page with the Fetch as Googlebot tool but got same error.

Anyone knows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development).

Answer (score 4):

Your web server is returning a 503 error when the user-agent string says the request is from Googlebot, but 200 when it's from a browser. If you use an http diagnostic tool such as Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) you can see this.

If you use Fiddler to send the same request that a browser would send:

```
GET http://www.hyponomist.com/robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.hyponomist.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 21:34:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Retry-After: 18000
Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 20:43:28 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

If you change the user-agent to mimic Googlebot:

```
GET http://www.hyponomist.com/robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.hyponomist.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Then the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 21:35:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 234
Connection: keep-alive
Retry-After: 18000
```

Exactly why it's doing this, I can't tell you. 503 is normally the error sent when a server is temporarily overloaded, but that's clearly not the case here. Maybe your firewall is poorly configured, and has blacklisted Googlebot based on request frequency? Take a look at your firewall settings and your server config.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the trailing slash (use http://www.hyponomist.com instead of http://www.hyponomist.com/) may help